# How to populate a Silvertripe 3.1 Gridfield With Images

Tags: silverstripe

how do I populate a Gridfield With Images from an external Url?
I can populate the gridfield with the actual url text, or even something like `<img src="...">`, but how do I render it so it actually shows the image?

```
class GalleryPage extends Page
...
    $list = $this->getListofImages();
    $grid = new GridField('GridFieldName', 'Gallery of', $list);
    $config = $grid->getConfig();
    $dataColumns = $config->getComponentByType('GridFieldDataColumns');
    $dataColumns->setDisplayFields(array(
        "Image" => "Image",
        'Title' => 'Title', 'Tags' => "Tags",
        'Url' => "Url", 'ThumbUrl' => 'ThumbUrl'));

    $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.ImportGallery', array( $grid ));
```

I'm only using this in the admin so I'm not using a template file.
"Image" is where I want to show the actual image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to jfbarrois, here's the answer -

```
$dataColumns->setFieldFormatting(array(
    "Image" => function($value, $item) {
        return '<img src="' . $item->Image . '"/>';
}
));
```

`$item->Image` here is a string of the url not an actual image.  Could also have used `$item->Url` or `$item->ThumbUrl` also in the original code.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following

```
$dataColumns->setFieldFormatting(array(
    "Image" => function($value, $item) {
        return '<img src="' . $item->getAbsoluteURL() . '"/>';
    }
);
```

You might need to tweak how the url is pulled, depending on what $list is made of, but that is the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it didn't work, however it helped me find the answer.  Because 'Image' was just the url as a string in the question the answer is just to change the return with your example above -
    return '<img src="' . $item->Image . '">'; 
or could have used $result = '<img src="' . $item->ThumbUrl. '">'; as it also was a string of the url.  Thanks very much!